# two conditions with two columns and two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
          select distinct a.name,a.id,a.icon,a.Agrippa from em a
          inner join pref b on a.id = b.id
          where a.name in ('Irish','jags')
          and a.icon in ('app','net','res')
          and a.Agrippa= 'mac'
          or
          (b.res = 'new'
          and a.icon in ('site'))
```

when i applied this code i am getting all the data. Instead my b.res condition didn't worked. If it works i would have get only recent fresh data but i was not. Not sure where i am getting issue can some one help me out.

Comment: Missing parenthesis - should be where `(a.name in ('Irish','jags')
          and a.icon in ('app','net','res')
          and a.Agrippa= 'mac') or (b.res = 'new'
          and a.icon in ('site'))`

Comment: "only recent fresh data".  I don't see a relationship between that and this query.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.

Comment: @ZoharPeled tried but same result any alter

Comment: @GordonLinoff if i could keep b.res = 'new' then i should get data w.r.t of res and refresh data. i tried in individual table it was working when i try to implement merging it couldn't. can you suggest any alter for my ask.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want an `AND` rather than an `OR`. At present you will get data that matches all of those first elements OR stuff that matches new data, so all the old stuff that matches and any new stuff.

If you only want new, then the b.res section is another AND.
:

```
      select distinct a.name,a.id,a.icon,a.Agrippa from em a
      inner join pref b on a.id = b.id
      where a.name in ('Irish','jags')
      and a.icon in ('app','net','res')
      and a.Agrippa= 'mac'
      and b.res = 'new'
      and a.icon in ('site')
```

Comment: if i keep the condition in a new line then my desire  condition doesn't working. Its like i am trying to merge two tables with two different conditions without b.res its giving one data. later i should use b.res and a.icon condition to get another filter data.

Comment: Dinesh - As asked above - can you post some sample data and your desired outcome. I think it will help us understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: hey hi @iainc Thanks for your support i think i am done seems to be. I just excluded all fields in one case and remains i put into second where condition and i  got desired output. But your condition makes think about in other condition too thanks for that.